# Realtime Query on Google Datastore

Tags: api, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible to run a "streaming" query from Google's Datastore real-time so that incoming data can progressively be pushed to the client instead of just grabbing a bunch of data at the point of query? I imagine the effect would be something like what AWS DynamoDB Streams API has implemented here (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html)

In the event if streaming query is not supported by Datastore, is there any other way I can retrieve data from Datastore real-time?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to go with createReadStream or runQueryStream.

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/datastore

Comment: Thanks for the reference! It looks like what I'm looking for, except that I'm trying to find a corresponding method for google-cloud-php but couldnt' seem to find any. Do you happen to know if this is supported for php?

Comment: As far as I can see, currently, there are no such functionality in client library for PHP. I run through source code, and streaming was enabled only for blobs, but just as argument to read the file as a blob.
So, you should consider to write some wrapper, maybe for that, but anyway, that will be separate batches reading.

Comment: I just switched to Node JS and would like to clarify that the above methods are used for fetching the data as a stream, and not for establishing an open connection to the datastore so that new data will be pushed over. Looks like the only way to implement live streaming data is through regular polling of the datastore..